# How to befriend QEventLoop and winapi event loop

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, event-loop

I have `MyApp` class with winapi event loop in it

```
class MyApp : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    int WINAPI exec() {
        MSG msg;
        int nRetVal;
        while ((nRetVal = ::GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) != 0 && nRetVal != -1) {
            ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
            ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        return msg.wParam;
    }
};
```

When I start my program, `QObject`'s events won't process (can't invoke any slot and hence send signals).
Somewhere on the internet I found kind of a solution - create a `QApplication` object, so it somehow "hooks up" to winapi message loop and it worked:

```
int main(int _argc, char* _argv[]) {
    QApplication qa(_argc,_argv);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(qa);

    MyApp mapp();
    return mapp.exec();
}
```

But it seems to me that design is fragile and a hack. And I don't like that I'm using some undocumented feature and never call `QApplication.exec()` method.
Can you tell me how to do it the right way? Namely, I want to call only one exec method (I guess it will be the one of `QApplication`, but where should I put my winapi loop?)
Thanks for any help

Comment: It's hard to advise you when we don't know what your class is trying to do and you feel the need to implement a message loop in it. What is not at all obvious is why you want to go behind the back of the framework. You opted to use Qt, so why are you fighting against it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In `MyApp` I call [CreateWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create hidden window and use eventloop to process its messages. I use that window for calls to [Shell_NotifyIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for example.

Comment: It seems like [QWinHost](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-solutions/blob/master/qtwinmigrate/src/qwinhost.cpp) can be of use, but I'm not sure

Comment: `SetWindowLongPtr`? As long as you have the window's handle, you can subclass (read: replace) the window procedure, handle the messages you want to handle, and call the original procedure for the rest.

Comment: @theB I use it to get/set pointer to `MyApp` instance but I don't see how your suggestion would solve my problem with 2 eventloops?

Comment: You have 3 problems: `1` Creating your own event loop is fighting the framework. `2` The assumption that native windows somehow need special treatment. `3` Using Qt. Qt is broken and cannot be fixed. If you need to implement a reliable Windows application, Qt cannot be used.

Comment: Why can't you just use a window created by the Qt framework to process your shell icon notifications? Why do you have to go outside of the framework?

Comment: @CodyGray can you elaborate? AFAIK by "Qt Window" you mean QtWidget? How can I get window handle from it for passing it to "Shell_NotifyIcon"?

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov, did you try [QSystemtrayIcon](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsystemtrayicon.html#details)?

Comment: @IInspectable I removed winapi event loop and callback function of `MyApp` is still being called, I wonder why? Thanks for stating my "problems" ))

Comment: @DmitrySokolov thanks, nice suggestion, noted. Too bad I didn't think about it before. As long as current code works I won't touch it